# How can I retrieve a document by _id?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve a document when I have an object id - however, the query does not work.

```
@collection = @db.collection('Mylist')
@result = @collection.find({"_id" => params[:id]})
```

I've tried variations of the query - it always yields empty - however when I try a query on the collection such as below, that would work.

```
@result = @collection.find({"Exist" => "True"})
```

Why? It is strange that complex queries work but a simple query by _id returns nothing.

If possible, I don't want to use MongoMapper.

Thanks

Comment: Found it - you need to wrap it like this - find({"_id" => Mongo::ObjectId(params[:id])})

Comment: Looks like you found the answer :) You should submit it as an "answer" below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it - you need to wrap it like this -

```
find({"_id" => Mongo::ObjectId(params[:id])})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find(:_id => BSON::ObjectID(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 2):

This would also work:
 @coll.find_one(ObjectID.from_string(params[:id]))