# Search document in MongoDB by _id using Flask-pymongo extension

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am baffled with the following problem.

I am using Flask, flask-pymongo extension, mongodb version v2.2.0-rc0, pdfile version 4.5

This is my route:

```
@app.route("/check/<id>")
def check(id):
   doc=conn.db.msg.find_one({'_id':id})
   return render_template('base.html',name=doc)
```

the id is a valid _id from a document in the msg collection, but ALWAYS return None.

I have tried:

- pasing the ObjectId(id) but returns errortype: ObjectId not callable
- pasing the id as str(id) returns None

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
this how the full url looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/check/5030b628895b800de1a9a792
```

UPDATE2:

I found a similar question with (answer) for ruby. Not sure how I can translate it to python, what sort imports/modules do I need?

[How can I retrieve a document by _id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235262/how-can-i-retrieve-a-document-by-id)

UPDATE3:
I tried:

```
import bson
@app.route("/check/<id>")
def check(id):
id2="'"+id+"'"
doc=conn.db.msg.find_one({'_id':bson.objectid(id2) })
return render_template('base.html',name=doc)
```

but I get **TypeError: 'module' object is not callable** (it doesnt work with id either)

when I reached 1500 I will suggest a **frustation** tag :-S

UPDATE4:

Finally I got it up & running!

here it is my solution:

```
import bson
@app.route("/check/<id>")
def check(id):
doc=conn.db.msg.find_one({'_id':bson.ObjectId(oid=str(id))})
return render_template('base.html',name=doc)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You might also want to try using `ObjectId` from the `bson.objectid` module, like so:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

In that case, you won't need to provide the `oid` kwarg. You'll just do something like this:

```
db_conn.msg.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(my_oid)})
```

Comment: By the way, we're updating the PyMongo docs for the next release to warn people about this pitfall:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/commit/dcf546f0b08e59d0d2c4f09a08fd9fe07017256a

Hope that helps.

Comment: the import has moved to `from bson.objectid import Objectid`

Comment: there is an error  `from bson.py3compat import abc, string_type, PY3, text_type
ImportError: cannot import name 'abc' from 'bson.py3compat'`

Comment: dont install bson at atll, currently there is  this above error

Comment: do we have any other option to get the objectid function?